# "Cannot launch program 'E:\typescriptBasis\main.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found."

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript with visual studio code in Windows 10 and I am getting an error to run simple program.
"Cannot launch program 'E:\typescriptBasis\main.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found." hence I am not able to debug code.

I have installed nodejs version v10.2.1
I have installed npm version v5.6.0
I have installed typescript globally v2.8.3
I have installed Visual sudio code v1.23.1

launch.json file

```
  "version": "0.2.0",   
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.ts",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

tsconfig.json file

```
{  
  "compilerOptions": {   
    "target": "es5",                     
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "sourceMap": true   
    }   
}
```

---

tasks.json

```
{   
    "version": "2.0.0",   
    "tasks": [   
        {    
            "type": "typescript",   
            "tsconfig": ".vscode\\tsconfig.json",   
            "option": "watch",   
            "problemMatcher": [   
                "$tsc-watch"   
            ]   
        },   
        {   
            "type": "typescript",   
            "tsconfig": ".vscode\\tsconfig.json",   
            "problemMatcher": [   
                "$tsc"   
            ],   
            "group": {   
                "kind": "build",   
                "isDefault": true   
            }   
        }    
    ]   
}
```

---

main.ts file

console.log("this is my first program of typescript");

Comment: You have to run `tsc` in the terminal to generate a .js file

Comment: Yes, I did that also  >>tsc main.ts and js file also generated. but still, I have the same issue...

Comment: how are you trying to run the .js file? in node ? `node main.js` or in a browser? `<script src='main.js'>`

Comment: I am just running the application in Visual Studio code. there is run an icon. after click on that, I am getting an error.

Comment: I think the run icon is for debugging? You still need to compile your .ts file to a .js file, for example by typing `tsc` in the terminal or pressing cmd+shift+b

Comment: Thank you so much it is working now....

Answer (score 3):

I have it working with the following
**launch.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "preLaunchTask": "TSC",
            "program": "${file}",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",        
    "module": "commonjs",      
    "allowJs": false,          
    "sourceMap": true,         
    "strict": true,            
    "noUnusedLocals": true,    
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true    
  }
}
```

and **tasks.json**:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "TSC",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And my current version of VS Code is 1.28.2

Comment: Version 1.41.1 works well, but it has something weird. 
If I include my explicit typescript, it doesn't work.